# Cucumber reports to include failure reasons when integrated with jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, cucumber

i am using Selenium Web driver with Cucumber for test automation. To see the reports i am integrating with Jenkins. I am able to see the report from jenkins. It is providing the status as Passed or failed. I need to add the reasons for these failures in the report. A new column next to status has to be included for the reasons. Can anyone please help me on this as i am new to these topics?

Comment: Search for some tutorials on Google.

Comment: if you view the build console log in jenkins it should have cucumber output which would show failures

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can able to view the failure reason when i click on the scenario. But i need the reason to appear in the statistics report next to "Status column"

Answer (score 0):

It might be hard to include the reason of the feature failure because reason may be different for different scenarios.

What I recommend is to publish the report over Jenkins using plusgin such as [Cucumber-JVM Reports](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Reports+Plugin)